# get union type of object keys filtered by type of object value

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to get union type of object keys filtered by type of object value?

I think, type inferring in conditional type is suitable for that, so I tried below. (`KeyOfValueType` is what I want)

```js
type Obj1 = { a: string, b: number };
type Obj2 = { c: number, d: string, e: string };

type KeyOfValueType<
    Obj extends {},
    ValueType extends Obj[keyof Obj]
> = ValueType extends Obj[infer K] ? K : never;

type Result1 = KeyOfValueType<Obj1, number>; // "b" because Obj1["b"] is equal to number
type Result2 = KeyOfValueType<Obj2, string>; // "d" | "e" because Obj2["d"] and Obj2["e"] are equals to string;
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=6&module=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwIxQLxQN5QIYC4oDOwATgJYB2A5gDRRz7kCuAtnBMVAL4DcAUKJFiIATGkxQAxgxZtitACb4iZKrQhKSFSlz79w0ANIQQMAGYA1bABtGEACr6APLyiuhCKBAAewCOXkEmJzULm6WNvb6nj5+Ae4A2gDWxgD2pu4AurwAfGLhtg6C3r7+gfAI8RSm7FAGGVAA-LVQDBAAbuy6AtAAShAEjFbAKOhGJhbWBU7lSLRMrOzZ3FAA9CtQAERwG3QQEtiMBNAz8Vsb9aSBEACOjNZQwClQ87J6gn0DQ6Kjxmb5kZBHOVhLRlFolqt1ht5DsAD6bCA7Nj7Q7HESnGH1bD+dzCU6IrHEaA3O5WQKPQiaKh8IA)

But tt raises an error `Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'Obj'.` at `Obj[infer K]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the package https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types.
It has `PickByValue` and `PickByValueExact` operators(and many other useful type operators). You can use them along with `keyof` to achieve your goal. They indeed use conditional type and `infer` for that.

```
type PickByValue<T, ValueType> = Pick<T, {
    [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends ValueType ? Key : never;
}[keyof T]>;

type R1 = keyof PickByValue<Obj1, number> //b
type R2 = keyof PickByValue<Obj2, string> //d | e
```